# Pagination not working on Wordpress search template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a function built for paginated loop results in Wordpress. This function is working throughout the site in all cases with the exception of its inclusion in the **search.php** template file. The buttons are displaying but not working when clicked.

I can not figure out why it would not be working in this case. My code is as follows:

a) Function in **functions.php** theme template file:

```
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2, $query = false) {  
$showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

global $paged;
if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

if($query == false) {       
    global $wp_query;
    $query = $wp_query;
}

if($pages == '') {
    $pages = $query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$pages) {
        $pages = 1;
    }
}   

if(1 != $pages) {
    echo "<div class='loop-pagination'>";

        // if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
        // if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

        echo "<div class='loop-pagination--button'>";
            if($paged > 1) { 
                    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='" . ($paged - 1) . "' class='loop-pagination--arrow-left'>NEWER POSTS</a>";
            } else {
                echo '&nbsp;';
            }
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class='loop-pagination--numbers'>";
        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='" . ($i) . "' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
            }
        }
        echo "</div>";

        // if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
        // if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";


        echo "<div class='loop-pagination--button'>";
            if($paged < $pages) { 
                echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='" . ($paged + 1) . "' class='loop-pagination--arrow-right'>OLDER POSTS</a>";
        // changed on 26th June 2017 to fix errors
        // 'javascript:void(0)' and '$paged + 1' on line 1688, from # and $paged - 1
        // also fixed error on line 1688 - # to 'javascript:void(0)'
            } else {
                echo '&nbsp;';
            }
        echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>\n";
} }
```

b) Call to function in **category-loop.php** theme template file (working):

```
<?php

// i.e. Explore More of ..... block

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'cat' => $data['cat']
    )
);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    if($data['title']) {
        echo '<h2 class="card-grid--title">' . $data['title'] . '</h2>';
    }

global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
$arr = explode("/page/", $current_url);
$push_url_base = $arr[0];

echo '<div id="ajax-load" data-post-type="post" data-category="' . $data['cat'] . '">';
    echo '<div class="card-grid align-left owl-carousel card-container">';

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $post_image = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/post-placeholder.png';
            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                $post_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'post-thumb');
            }

            $cat = get_the_category();

            load_component('post-card', array(
                'link' => get_the_permalink(),
                'image' => $post_image,
                'title' => comp_title_filter(get_the_title()),
                'date' => get_the_modified_date('jS M Y'),
                'category' => get_cat_name($cat[count($cat) - 1]->category_parent),
                // 'category' => 'Example',
                'excerpt' => false,
                'icon' => find_post_icon(get_the_ID()),
                'link_target' => false,
                'sharing' => true,
                'count' => false
            ));
        }

    echo '</div>';

    wp_reset_postdata();
    kriesi_pagination('', 2, $the_query);

echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

c) Call to function in **search.php** (not working):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>

<?php

$post_image = get_field('default_background_image', 'option');

if(get_search_query()) {
    $page_title = 'Search Results for "'.get_search_query().'"';
} else {
    $page_title = 'Search';
}

load_component('hero-block', array(
    'title' => $page_title,
    'background_image' => $post_image,
    'text' => false,
    'tagline' => false,
    'hero_tint' => false
));

?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="page-container">

        <form method="get" class="destination-search" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
            <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" class="destination-search--input" id="search-input" placeholder="Search">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="destination-search--submit">
        </form>


        <?php
        $letter_array = array('a'=>array(),'b'=>array(),'c'=>array(),'d'=>array(),'e'=>array(),'f'=>array(),'g'=>array(),'h'=>array(),'i'=>array(),'j'=>array(),'k'=>array(),'l'=>array(),'m'=>array(),'n'=>array(),'o'=>array(),'p'=>array(),'q'=>array(),'r'=>array(),'s'=>array(),'t'=>array(),'u'=>array(),'v'=>array(),'w'=>array(),'x'=>array(),'y'=>array(),'z'=>array());

        $idObj = get_category_by_slug('holiday-destinations');

        if($idObj) {
            $id = $idObj->term_id;

            $categories = get_term_children( $id, 'category');

            foreach($categories as $category) {
                $cats = get_category($category);
                if($cats->category_parent !== $id) {
                    $first_letter = strtolower(substr($cats->name ,0, 1));
                    $letter_array[$first_letter][] = $cats;
                }
            }
        }



        function order_cities($a, $b) {
            return strtolower($a->name) > strtolower($b->name);
        }


        ?>

        <?php
        $search_term = strtolower(get_search_query());
        foreach($letter_array as $letter => $cities) {
            if(count($cities) > 0) {
                usort($cities, 'order_cities');
                foreach($cities as $city) {
                    if ($search_term && strpos(strtolower($city->name), $search_term) !== false) {
                        if($destination_found == false) {
                            echo '<h2 class="card-grid--title">Destinations matching your search:</h2>';
                            echo '<div class="card-grid align-left">';
                            $destination_found = true;
                        }

                        $post_image = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/post-placeholder.png';
                        if(get_field('cat_header_image', 'term_' . $city->term_id)) {
                            $post_image = get_field('cat_header_image', 'term_' . $city->term_id)['sizes']['post-thumb'];
                        }

                        load_component('post-card', array(
                            'link' => get_category_link($city->term_id),
                            'image' => $post_image,
                            'title' => $city->name,
                            'date' => false,
                            'category' => get_cat_name($city->parent),
                            'excerpt' => false,
                            'icon' => false,
                            'link_target' => false,
                            'sharing' => false,
                            'count' => false
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if($destination_found == true) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>

        <?php $totalPosts = $wp_query->post_count; $postCount = 0;
        // var_dump($wp_query);
        if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <h2 class="card-grid--title">Articles matching your search:</h2>
            <div class="card-grid">
                <?php rewind_posts(); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $postCount++; $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
                    <?php
                    $post_image = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/post-placeholder.png';
                    if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        $post_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'post-thumb');
                    }

                    $author_data = get_userdata(get_the_author_meta('ID'));
                    load_component('post-card', array(
                        'link' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'image' => $post_image,
                        'title' => comp_title_filter(get_the_title()),
                        'date' => get_the_modified_date('jS M Y'),
                        'category' => false,
                        'excerpt' => wpautop(get_the_excerpt()),
                        'icon' => false,
'link_target' => false,
                        'sharing' => true,
                        'count' => false
                    ));
                    ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if($postCount == $totalPosts) : ?>
                <div class="static-nav-container">
                    <?php echo kriesi_pagination('', 2, $the_query); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have tried to find the reason why this pagination is not working on search and I am very stuck. Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Example: https://famtravsticky1.staging.wpengine.com/?s=beach

Example (working): https://famtravsticky1.staging.wpengine.com/holiday-destinations/indian-ocean/mauritius/

Comment: Error in your scripts-min.js  `TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined`

Comment: I am not sure but try to mix PHP and HTML codes like category-loop.php
I mean use `<?php echo 'HTML code'; ?>` instead of `<?php ...?>HTML code <?php ... ?>`